# PHP print variable from input

Tags: php, post

I have following code and it doesn't works for me.

I need print variable from input.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action='#' method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">  
    </form>

      <?php
         $name = name
         echo $name; 
      ?>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Recommend you read the [PHP manual on dealing with forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).

Comment: `= name` has numerous issues. You should look at a PHP tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use POST to get text from input.

This is right code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action='#' method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit">  
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name; 
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should at least check if the form has been submitted, to avoid getting notices.

Comment: You could also make this a bit shorter.
`echo (isset($_POST['submit'])) ? $_POST['name'] : '';`